# React Native, Navigating a prop from one component to another

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, fetch-api

```html
handleShowMatchFacts = id => {
  //  console.log('match', id)
    return fetch(`http://api.football-api.com/2.0/matches/${id}?Authorization=565ec012251f932ea4000001fa542ae9d994470e73fdb314a8a56d76`)
    .then(res => { 
   //   console.log('match facts', matchFacts)
        this.props.navigator.push({
        title: 'Match',
        component: MatchPage,
        passProps: {matchInfo: res}

     })
       // console.log(res)
  }) 
}
```

I have this function above, that I want to send `matchInfo` to `matchPage`.

I take in that prop as follows below:

```html
'use strict'

import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Component, Text, TabBarIOS } from 'react-native'
import Welcome from './welcome.js'
import More from './more.js'

export default class MatchPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentWillMount(){

    console.log('mathc facts ' + this.props.matchInfo._bodyInit)
  }



    render(){
        return (
            <View>

      </View>

        )
    }
}
```

All the info I need is in that object - `this.props.matchInfo._bodyInit`. My problem is that after `._bodyInt`, I'm not sure what to put after that. I've tried `.id`, `.venue`, and `.events`, they all console logged as undefined...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you are receiving json object as response , you would need to parse the response before fetching the values.

```
var resp = JSON.parse(matchInfo);
body = resp['_bodyInit'];
```

Comment: Thank You man!!! YOU SOLVED MY ISSUE!! thanks for responding to me bro!!

Comment: Great.. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You never change props directly in React. You must always change the state via **setState** and pass state to components as props. This allows React to manage state for you rather than calling things manually.

In the result of your api call, set the **component state**:

```
this.setState({
    title: 'Match',
    component: MatchPage,
    matchInfo: res
}
```

Then pass the state as needed into child components.

```
render() {
        return(
            <FooComponent title={this.state.title} matchInfo={this.state.matchInfo} />
        );
    }
```

These can then be referenced in the child component as **props**:

```
class FooComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        console.log(this.props.title);
        console.log(this.props.matchInfo);
        // Etc.
    }
}
```

If you need to reference these values inside the component itself, reference **state** rather than **props**.

```
this.state.title;
this.state.matchInfo;
```

Remember components manage their own state and pass that state as props to children as needed.

Comment: hey man, thanks for the response, but your answer dosent help me out, i tried your way, but the app doset navigate to the new component